# Generic parameters for Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, neural-network, particle-swarm

I understand how Particle Swarm Optimization works in general and have read about it in several articles. It is noticeable that most writing about PSO focuses on optimizing single-equation functions. In Pedersen's Good Parameters for Particle Swarm Optimization, he gives 18 results from when he meta-optimized PSO for about ten benchmark problems, with seven numbers of dimensions (from 2 to 100).

I want to optimize a Multi-Layer Perceptron with PSO. I've successfully done it in Matlab for some rather small MLPs, but not nearly as large as I want. (100 dimensions is gigantic for single-equation functions, but it's a teensy-weensy number of weights and biases in a neural network. I expect to need on the order of 800,000 weights and biases - dimensions - to be optimized in my final program.)

My problem, as I understand it, is that I can't find a simple explanation for how to choose the values of `w`, `c1`, and `c2`* such that any function with any number of dimensions can be optimized. (I'm sure that's asking way too much, but at least a function that, while it has step discontinuities, resembles smooth on a large scale, and doesn't have white noise.)

Or has anyone meta-optimized PSO for neural networks in general?

Answer (score 1):

In all types of population based methods, the problem of how to choose parameters is a challenging one. It is mostly done by testing out multiple sets of parameters and then choosing the best set for the task. Luckily for you though, the goal of PSO is to converge at an optimal location and A. Engelbrecht has proved that not all sets of parameters converge. [Here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/270d/24da13010c775f3b09b9fc53b2e612fc97aa.pdf) is a paper that has the explanation. **The convergence conditions are listed on pages 945 and 947**. I'm sure you can also find the paper that was released in the references listed in the slide. Beyond that narrowing, you just need to find the balance of exploration and exploitation that suits your specific problem.

Also, I would like to let you know that from my experience using PSO to evolve neural networks is nowhere near as effective as just using general backprop methods as long as your data is static. If you are working in a dynamic environment then a quantum/charged PSO is a better choice.

I hope this has narrowed down your search for parameters and provided you with some additional insight.

Edit:

Replaced the link with a paper with a similar graph
Note:

A paper that includes the graph:

"A study of particle swarm optimization particle trajectories" F. van den Bergh, A.P. Engelbrecht

Comment: Thanks, but I clicked the link and got an error. Are you logged in to ACM?

Comment: Sorry about that. I was on a university network, but it seems to have disappeared for me as well. I have updated the link to a paper which has the diagram